# How to save value of JSON data to db in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to store json data to database, data being fetched from 3rd party api.

**sample of json:**

```
 [{ "name"=>"test", "number"=>"1234", "email"=>"test@t.com"},
  { "name"=>"user", "number"=>"5678", "email"=>"yser@t.com"}]
```

Model contains: `username, number_phone, y_email`

I want to store `name` in `username` and `number` in `number_phone`.

**Fetching the data:**

```
rdb = RestdbApi.new
body = rdb.call
```

**Updated**

> Need store all data json not first element only
>
> Data json change continuously need save continuously

Comment: `JSON.parse(body)[0]['name']` will get you to the name. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks @Phlip but need store all data not first element only

Answer (score 0):

If you already have everything setup to get your response you can do something like this:

```
response = [{ "name"=>"test", "number"=>"1234", "email"=>"test@t.com"}]

YourModel.create(
  username: response[0]["name"],
  number_phone: response[0]["number"],
  y_email: response[0]["email"]
)
```

The above shows you how to access an index for the response that you displayed, then creating your object with the response attributes. If you are expecting to have multiple in the response, you should use a loop and do something similar:

```
response = [{ "name"=>"test", "number"=>"1234", "email"=>"test@t.com"}, { "name"=>"test", "number"=>"1234", "email"=>"test@t.com"}]

response.each_with_index do |_, i|
  YourModel.create(
    username: response[i]["name"],
    number_phone: response[i]["number"],
    y_email: response[i]["email"]
  )
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could have this in a model, but if it were me I would put it in a place like `app/services/`

Comment: when added code in model or controller appear this error `no implicit conversion of Array into String` i already have  `RestdbApi` add this code same file?

Comment: What does your response look like?

Comment: Do you get that error when doing `result_json = JSON.parse(body)`? (from the above answer)

Comment: yes appear error when doing `result_json = JSON.parse(body)`

Comment: That error tells me you already have the response in an array. Without seeing exactly what you are doing, find the attributes within your `body` and save them to the model

Comment: yes response array . response by online database. how do that?

Comment: If your array looks like the one in my answer then the code that I put should be what you are looking for (you would need to add your model name)

Comment: i updated example json data in question . this code in model  `rdb = RestdbApi.new
 body = rdb.call  # [{ "name"=>"test", "number"=>"1234", "email"=>"test@t.com"}]
 result_json = JSON.parse(body)
 User.create(
    username: result_json[0]["name"],
    number_phone: result_json[0]["number"],
)` what change ?

Comment: `rdb.call` already returns the array for you. You don't need to use `JSON.parse(body)`

Comment: Thanks you this error solve. but when `rails c` no any data in model

Comment: i need store all data json not one element?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking. Store the entire json in an _one_ attribute?

Comment: data json change continuously need save continuously

Answer (score 0):

As per the description shared if I am assuming it right, you need to fetch values from json and save it in the respective columns in database.

For the same, suppose you have a json(let's name it as result_json), as mentioned in the post:

```
rdb = RestdbApi.new
body = rdb.call  # [{ "name"=>"test", "number"=>"1234", "email"=>"test@t.com"}]
result_json = JSON.parse(body)
```

Now suppose you have a user class which is mapped to the db for saving respective values, then

```
user = User.new
user.username = result_json[0]["name"]
user.number_phone = result_json[0]["number"]
user.save # note that this line will map the records in the User instance to the database.
```

Comment: when added code in model or controller appear this error `no implicit conversion of Array into String `

Comment: please check if body is an array or not...if it is an array then no need for JSON.parse(body)

Comment: not use `result_json = JSON.parse(body)` because already use the line in `RestdbApi` but save all again and is very slow when open `view`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this

`rest_db_api = RestdbApi.new`

`user_records_from_api = JSON.parse(rest_db_api.call)`

(I will assume that `user_records_from_api` will now contain an array of hashes, as follows:

`[{ "name"=>"test", "number"=>"1234", "email"=>"test@t.com"},{ "name"=>"user", "number"=>"5678", "email"=>"yser@t.com"}]`

you can then just iterate over this hash and create a record for each (I am assuming that your model is called `User`)

```
user_records_from_api.map(&:with_indifferent_access).each do |attribues|
  User.create!(
    username: attributes[:name],
    number_phone: attributes[:number],
    y_email: attributes[:email]
  )
end
```

note: the `with_indifferent_access` method that I used is just a handy thing provided by the rails framework that allows you to have a hash with string keys, and access them using symbols (or vice-versa) - `ActionController::Parameters` (in rails) uses this

Comment: Thanks you! this solution store all record but when receive new json data save all data again?

Comment: Accept my answer then. You'll need to add some logic in there to check if it's an existing record if you want to handle updates as well. I'll start you off rather than just giving you the answer. Theres a method `persisted?` that you can call on an `ActiveRecord` object to check whether it's been saved or not, or better still you could just do a `find_by` and check if it's `nil`, then do an update with `update_attributes` if you find the existing record

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find_or_create_by`, to not duplicate the data. [LINK](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

```
rdb = RestdbApi.new
body = rdb.call

body.each do |data|
  # YourModel: make sure to change to yr own model name
  YourModel.find_or_create_by(email: data["y_email"])(
    username:     data["name"],
    number_phone: data["number"],
    y_email:      data["email"]
  )
end
```